# Maven SCM plugin fails to do a scm:update after a scm:checkout with obscure error message

Tags: git, maven, version-control, maven-scm-plugin

I have configured a maven project to checkout a project using:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@git.github.com:example/myproject.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Using: mvn scm:checkout

The project checks out fine.

I would expect if scm:checkout works, scm:update should work too. But it doesn't.
By running with the "-e" option (mvn -e scm:update) to get the full stack trace, it will show some obscure error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.8.1:update (default-cli) on project mysampleproject: Command failed.The git-log command failed. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.8.1:update (default-cli) on project mysampleproject: Command failed.The git-log command failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command failed.The git-log command failed.
    at org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.AbstractScmMojo.checkResult(AbstractScmMojo.java:439)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.UpdateMojo.execute(UpdateMojo.java:93)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Now what should this error tell me ? Is this probably a bug in the Maven-scm-Plugin? Cause "git-log" does of course not even exist, its "git log" that would give you the Git log history.

Also the given help link will not help (from my point of view).

Comment: `git-log` should exist or be aliased to `git log` -- if it's not, you should check your git installation

Comment: Sorry Nevik but that seems to be not true. On my Red Hat installation all git commands are git <SPACE> <command> . There is not a single git command that I can perform by using that syntax with a "-" instead of the <SPACE> ... and I think my git installation is quite fine.

Comment: Compare for example: http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/git/commands.htm ... there are no commands with a "-" instead of a space...

Comment: and if I would create this alias by doing: alias git-log='git log' ... and rerun Maven, I will receive the exactly same error/exception.

Comment: That command list has nothing to do with what git packages will install. I don't know how you installed git on your system, and i can't find any good source because "red hat" is a very general distribution name which covers lots of versions. I saw some Fedora RPMs which install the `git-<subcommand>` alternatives, i know that all debian packages install them, and so will git when you compile it from source.

Comment: Its Red Hat 6 Enterprise Distro. I still doubt that "git-log" is a general replacement to "git log". However setting this alias did also not resolve the maven-scm-plugin issues. The error message is exactly the same.

Comment: In configuration , along with connectionType do you also have checkoutDirectory, workingDirectory ?
This might solve the issue.